# If statement within javascript variable declaration

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have such variable declaration in my JavaScript method on :

```
var MyVariable = {
    CarMake: "Lexus",
    CarColor: "Black"
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to add some login within MyVariable declaration such as:

```
    var MyVariable = {
    CarMake: "Lexus",
    if (carType == "sedan") {
        NumberOfDoors: 4,
    }
    CarColor: "Black"
}
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 2):

With a one-line object you can't do it. You need to assign it later. But I thnik you can create a `class(ES6)` and use like

```js
class Car{
  constructor(maker, color, type){
      this.maker = maker;
      this.color = color;
      if(type === 'sedan'){
        this.numberOfDoors = 4;  
      }
  }
}

var car = new Car('Lexus','Black','sedan');
console.log(car.numberOfDoors);
```

Or use the `function` syntax

```js
    function Car(maker, color, type){    
          this.maker = maker;
          this.color = color;
          if(type === 'sedan'){
            this.numberOfDoors = 4;  
          }   
    }

    var car = new Car('Lexus','Black','sedan');
    console.log(car.numberOfDoors);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could do

```
var MyVariable = {
  CarMake: "Lexus",
  CarColor: "Black",
  NumberOfDoors: (carType === 'sedan') ? 4 : undefined
}
```

which is not exactly the same, but close.

---

But how about

```
var MyVariable = {
  CarMake: "Lexus",
  CarColor: "Black"
}

if (carType === 'sedan') {
    MyVariable.NumberOfDoors = 4
}
```

You could wrap this into a "factory" function and then do

```
var MyVariable = makeCar("Lexus", "Black", "sedan")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your variable before and add the new attribute after :

```
var MyVariable = {
   CarMake: "Lexus",
   CarColor: "Black"
}

if (carType == "sedan") {
    MyVariable.NumberOfDoors = 4
}
```

Comment: I think there is syntax issue here. The colon within if-statement should be replaced with equal sign to make if a statement if I am not mistaken. Anyway, good idea. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this:

```
var MyVariable = {
    CarMake: "Lexus",
    CarColor: "Black"
}

if (carType == "sedan") {
    MyVariable.NumberOfDoors = 4;
}
```